# Dealing with errors 403, 404 in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: taxonomy-terms, xml-sitemap

I know it may not be strictly drupal releated question, but I'm curious what would be the best approach to solve it with Drupal.

1. 403 errors to: `taxonomy/term/%/feed`

I have around 900 errors with 403 most of them look like this `taxonomy/term/26/all/feed` so they seem to be caused by `taxonomy/term/%/feed` and my question is how could I best fix this issue ?

So that Google would not penalize me with 404's after ? should I somehow change the view.. or ? not sure how to approach this maybe you have experienced similiar issue also when I try to accesss "`name_of_term/feed`" it doesnt seem to work

2. 404 errors exposed fields with `?field_name=value`

I have have around 200 errors of 404 type most of them look like this: `NAME_OF_TERM?field_brand_tid=All&field_color_tid=192&field_size_tid=253`

From what I understand it is showing options in exposed filters for items that doesn't have any nodes assigned to them.

Answer (score 1):

For Taxonomy terms you can use Disable Term Node Listings module (https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_term_node_listings)

There is also a great write up on drupal.org about similar issues: https://www.drupal.org/node/345620

In short use robots.txt to disallow paths like ones you specified above. This will prevent google from indexing those pages in first place.

Comment: The question is also what to do when they already got indexed ?

Comment: there is also the other fact, that I actually need to list items assigned to my taxonomy terms.. because thats why I use the terms in first place to display the nodes assigned to them in views for each vocabulary...

Comment: If they are already indexed, one way to remove them is to use xmlsitemap module and submit sitemap.xml to google via Google Console, formerly Google Webmaster Tools